# Issue With Variable Scope

Tags: javascript

*Please excuse the vague title. I'm not sure what is causing the problem and cannot be more specific.*

I have two consecutive function calls, where the first function is "messing" with the variable in my second function. Although it seems to me that all variables are local to their function.

```
var data = [    
    'Science Fiction',
    'Business / Management',
    'Business / Management / Leadership',
];

function getName(parts) {
    return parts[parts.length - 1];    
}

function getTrail(parts) {
    if (parts.length === 1) return null;
    parts.pop();
    return parts.join(' / ');
}

function getParents(parts) {
    if (parts.length === 1) return null;
    parts.pop();
    return parts;
}

function generate(path) {
    var parts = path.split(' / ');
    return {
        name: getName(parts),        
        trail: getTrail(parts), // <= Problem?
        parents: getParents(parts) // <= Last part is missing when getTrail(parts) is called before.
    };
}

var categories = data.map(generate);
```

Please see **http://jsfiddle.net/n6Dud/** for a better spaced and working example.

When you run the example, you can check your console and see that the last part in `object.parents` is missing. I suspect `parts.pop()` from `getTrail()`.

Why is that and how can I work around it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getTrail` pops the last element off of `parts`, and because `parts` is a reference to the original data the change is visible even after the function has returned.

You need to make the operation non-destructive instead by operating on a copy of `parts`. This can be done using [`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) to make a copy of everything but the last element:

```
if (parts.length === 1) return null;
return parts.slice(0, -1).join(' / ');
```

Answer (score 0):

When you pass an array in JavaScript you're effectively passing a *reference* to that array and not a copy of it.

Any modifications to that array will therefore also modify the original.  If you want to ensure that you *don't* modify the original you should take your own copy, e.g:

```
var copy = parts.slice(0);
```

Since as it happens you don't want the last element of the copy, you can strip that out at the time you take the copy:

```
var copy = parts.slice(0, -1);
```

Comment: Thanks Alnitak, I didn't know that's even so across functions.

Answer (score 0):

To make this work, you'll need to clone the object (which means you have to copy over all its properties to another object) to make sure the object you're editing is a different object. Objects behave different from other data types such as strings. For objects, the variable holds the object reference, and not the object itself. That makes it that passing the object through to another function, and then editing that object in the other function, you'll also edit your original object.

You can copy over objects by doing a simple forloop:

```
function cloneObj(o) {
    var clone = {};
    for (var i in o) {
        if (typeof o[i] === 'object') clone[i] = cloneObj(o[i]);
        else clone[i] = o[i];
    }
}
```

or for arrays, use the method Alnitak mentioned:

```
var copied = parts.slice(0);
```

Comment: Thank you too for your answer!